# Pattern Matching chooses the wrong case if used with ClassTag

Tags: scala, reflection, covariance

What is the connection between variance and `ClassTags` or `TypeTags`?

I have two types `T1` and `T2`, that are used as type params.

```
case class T1()
case class T2()
```

I have an abstract class with an invariant type parameter and one subclass, if I want to check the type of the type parameter it only works if there is no type check in the pattern, just in the guard. If a type test is present it always chooses the first case.

The type check is necessary because in my real code I want to call different functions for each type. There are separate functions for `In[T1]` and `In[T2]`.

```
abstract class In[T]
case class VIn[T]() extends In[T]

def test1[T:ClassTag](v:In[T]) = v match {
  case x : VIn[T1@unchecked] if classTag[T] == classTag[T1] => "T1"
  case y : VIn[T2@unchecked] if classTag[T] == classTag[T2] => "T2"
}
test1(VIn[T1]())  //T1
test1(VIn[T2]())  //T1 !!!

def test2[T:ClassTag](v:In[T]) = v match {
  case x if classTag[T] == classTag[T1] => "T1"
  case y if classTag[T] == classTag[T2] => "T2"
}
test2(VIn[T1]())  //T1
test2(VIn[T2]())  //T2
```

While playing around with the `List` type that's use in many examples, I realized that if the type parameter is changed to be covariant it works in both tests.

```
abstract class Co[+T]
case class VCo[T]() extends Co[T]

def test1[T:ClassTag](v:Co[T]) = v match {
  case x : VCo[T1@unchecked] if classTag[T] == classTag[T1] => "T1"
  case y : VCo[T2@unchecked] if classTag[T] == classTag[T2] => "T2"
}
test1(VCo[T1]())  // T1
test1(VCo[T2]())  // T2

def test2[T:ClassTag](v:Co[T]) = v match {
  case x if classTag[T] == classTag[T1] => "T1"
  case y if classTag[T] == classTag[T2] => "T2"
}
test2(VCo[T1]())  // T1
test2(VCo[T2]())  // T2
```

Why does the first tests fail for invarinat types? There isn't a compiler warning, or a runtime error, it just picks the first case, but  the guard is obviously false, as demonstrated in `test2`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. There isn't a compiler warning because you are using `@unchecked`. But it's odd that in your first example, `classTag[T1]` is actually `ClassTag[T2]` when passing `VIn[T2]`, so the result of the `if` statement is true. It's as if `T1` is being treated as `T2` for some reason. That said, the type test is fruitless, anyway, and you can do without it.

Comment: @m-z I need the type test, because I wan't to call a function `def foo(x:VIn[T1])` with `x` if `T =:= T1`. The type test makes the compiler belief that `x` is of type `VIn[T1]`, otherwise I get an error that `VIn[T]` can't be matched with `VIn[T1]`. I could use `instanceOf`, but having everything in the pattern match looks better to me.

Comment: `case VIn[T1]` isn't very useful though, and relies on the `ClassTag` comparisons. You could instead use `case VIn[_] if(classTag[T] == classTag[T1]) => ...`, which will still check for `VIn`, and not be subject to that bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely think it is a compiler bug.

```
def test1[T:ClassTag](v:In[T]) = {  
  val t1 = classTag[T] == classTag[T1]
  val t2 = classTag[T] == classTag[T2]

  println(v match {
    case x : VIn[T1@unchecked] if t1 => "T1"
    case y : VIn[T2@unchecked] if t2 => "T2"
  })

  v match {
  case x:In[T1] if classTag[T] == classTag[T1] => "T1"
  case y: In[T2] if classTag[T] == classTag[T2] => "T2"
}}
```

Printing with `-Xprint:typer` shows that (`evidence`):

```
def test1[T](v: In[T])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): String = {
....

val t1: Boolean = scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T](evidence$1).==
         (scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T1]((ClassTag.apply[T1](classOf[T1]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[T1]))) 


val t2: Boolean = scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T](evidence$1).==        
        (scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T2]((ClassTag.apply[T2](classOf[T2]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[T2]))) //classTag[T] == classTag[T2]
```

The `if` statement of the pattern match is:

```
scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T](evidence$1).==(scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T1](evidence$1))

scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T](evidence$1).==(scala.reflect.`package`.classTag[T2](evidence$1))
```

The compiler is passing `evidence$1` to the implicit argument of `classTag[1]()` and `classTag[2]()`. So it is actually comparing itself to itself. As a work around, as you suggested `test2`or a pre-calculated `if` seems to work.